# Error while getting GPS pos and parsing XML

Tags: android, xml, gps

Could anyone explain what causes this error:

I am using DOM to parse XML.

> 12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289): 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at gps.app.tkartor.Tkartor.onLocationChanged(Tkartor.java:205)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:191)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:124)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:140)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   12-12 08:56:52.053: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What's the use of the parser in GPS listener? Please post the code.

Comment: I just wanna know what's causing the error, not how to solve it. I'd like to figure that out myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check for null fields in the Location received in `onLocationChanged`. When there's no GPS coverage, dummy location objects are received.